# Comparing median and sum in python

Tags: python, median

I have data for businesses that has categories and review counts. I have grouped the categories together for each business and I want to separate out those businesses that have review counts that are above the median number of review counts within each category and those that are below the median number of review counts. Essentially, I need to return a Series of median values indexed by category and use that to find out if a given business is greater than the median for its category. I have to compare its review count to the median for its category.
My code is throwing errors and I can't figure out why. Suggestions? I've tried both of the below.

```
n = df.groupby('category')['review_count'].size()
def cats_median_split(n):
    s = df.groupby('category')['review_count'].median()
if n > s:
    return True
else:
    return False
df.groupby('category')['review_count'].apply(cats_median_split)
```

OR:

```
n = df.groupby('category')['review_count'].sum()
def cats_median_split(n): 
    s = n.median()
if n > s:
    return True
else:
    return False
df.groupby('category')['review_count'].apply(cats_median_split)
```

Comment: Post the errors. Edit your question to include the full traceback. A sample of your data is also important to providing a [mcve]. You may benefit from [ask].

Comment: Post the actual errors and probably change the question title to reflect the actual errors you're getting, not the general problem you're trying to solve

Comment: What are you doing in your code. What is df? For one thing, your indentation is incorrect, at least here it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you wish to:

```
def median (seq, index=0):
    customcmp = lambda x, y: cmp(x[index], y[index])
    seq = sorted(seq, customcmp)
    l = len(seq)
    if l%2==0:
        return (seq[l/2-1][index]+seq[l/2][index])/2.0
    return seq[l/2][index]

def split (seq, index=0, trashhold=0):
    left = []; right = []
    for element in seq:
        if element[index]<trashhold:
            left.append(element)
        else:
            right.append(element)
    return left, right

cats = [(123, 345), (99, 258), (9753, 36754), (234, 216), (123456, 76543)]
m = median(cats, 1)
split(cats, 0, m)

For median you better use numpy, but for smaller sequences this implementation will do.
```